# How can i hide a Screen while traversing backwards

Tags: install4j

I have multiple Screens defined in my Install4J-Project.

Assuming that i have 3 Screens called:

- "Screen 1"
- "Screen 2"
- "Screen 3"

Screen 2 is configure as follows:
Post-activation script:

```
context.getWizardContext().setControlButtonVisible(ControlButtonType.NEXT, false);
context.getWizardContext().setControlButtonVisible(ControlButtonType.PREVIOUS, false);
context.goForward(1, true, true);
```

The current Behaviour is as follows:

1. I'm in "Screen 1" and click "Next"
2. Install4J jumps to "Screen 2". The Postactivationscript here hides the Back and Next Buttons and clicks "Next" for me.
3. I'm in "Screen 3".

That's the Behaviour i expected so far.

Following the Description of the as-is and unwanted Behaviour with my current Configuration.

*If i now click the "Back"-Button in "Screen 3", Install4J jumps back to "Screen 2", but the Postactivationscript will bounce me instantly back to "Screen 3".*

My Question now is:

What do i have to change, to get so following Behaviour?

*If i now click the "Back"-Button in "Screen 3", Install4J skips "Screen 2" on traversing back and show me "Screen 1".

So i want to show "Screen 2" on Forward-Traversal and hide it on Backward-Traversal. Is this possible?

According to the Install4J Help there are Methods like [isHiddenForPrevious](https://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/api/com/install4j/api/screens/Screen.html#isHiddenForPrevious--) that seem to be able to accomplish my Task but how and where do i use them and how do i configure "Screen 2" to hide on Backward-Traversal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a good use case that is currently not covered for configurable forms. In 7.0.4 we will add a "Screen can be reached" property that can be set to "Only with Next button". Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this already implemented.

Comment: I'm wondering why the following lines in the Field "Postactivation-Script" prevent the Back Traversal.

context.getWizardContext().setControlButtonVisible(ControlButtonType.NEXT, false);
context.getWizardContext().setControlButtonVisible(ControlButtonType.PREVIOUS, false);
context.goForward(1, true, true);

These Lines are defined in the "Screen 2". With these enabled, i'm unfortunately not able to jump from "Screen 3" to "Screen 1" although i have set "Only with Next button" for "Screen 2". I need to process "Screen 2" unattended and cannot skip it. What shall i do?

Comment: With the current build this works for me. with the same script. Please have a look at the log file .install4j\installation.log after the installation. When you go back you see lines in the log like `[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.FormScreen [ID 1565]: command: go back 1 screens using history` and then the skipped screen should not be activated. Do you compile the project from the command line build that may be using on older build of install4j?

Comment: Please apologize. Seems that i used the new Install4J-GUI, but my Buildscript used the old One. Indeed it works for this little Example at my Side now. I'll try to adopt it to the real Project. Thanks again for your Help!